# How to align something on both sides of an HTML page?

Tags: html

This may seem like a stupid question, but I need help. What would I write if I wanted to align some text to the left of the screen, and some on the right of the screen, both on the same line?

Comment: And in center there should be text or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `float:left` and `float:right` property of css.

Refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyu1ovd8/)

HTML:

```
<span class="float-l">left</span>
<span class="float-r">right</span>
```

CSS:

```
.float-l{
    float : left
}
.float-r{
    float: right
}
```

Comment: You should expand on your answer with an example.

Comment: Why did this answer win?  The float: left; is completely unnecessary here.  See my answer below, which is that same thing without the unneeded extra code.  The containing div and borders are for illustration only.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.  This is one.  The borders are just so it's easier to see.

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid red; }

span {
 border: 1px solid blue; }

.r {
 dislay: inline-block;
 float: right;
 text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div>
 <span>I'm Left</span>
 <span class="r">I'm Right</span>
</div>
```